# How to get the URL from this string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

How can i get the url from following

> [bpfb_link url='http://www.abcd.com/' title='abcd Technologies : :
>   Home Page' image='http://www.abcd.com//images/itwall_b1.gif']
>                   [/bpfb_link]

The above link i `retrieved` from the `php` method into a `xml`.How can i get a `formatted url` from the `above tag`.
I thought of using `componentsseperatedBystring` to get the string but the format changes everytime.
i was doing the following to remove the unwanted string

```
NSRange rangeLink = [[[arrUpdates valueForKeyPath:@"content"]objectAtIndex:intIndexPath] rangeOfString:@"bpfb_link"];
            if (rangeLink.location != NSNotFound) 
            {

            NSArray *arrNewLink=[[[arrUpdates valueForKeyPath:@"content"]objectAtIndex:intIndexPath] componentsSeparatedByString:@"["];
                NSLog(@"arrNewLink  %@",[arrNewLink objectAtIndex:0]);
                //[[arrNewLink objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"]"];

                NSArray *arrEditedLinks=[[arrNewLink objectAtIndex:1]componentsSeparatedByString:@"]"];
                 NSLog(@"arrEditedLinks  %@",[arrEditedLinks objectAtIndex:1] );
}
```

please help me out

Comment: use NSXMLParser for parsing xml data

Comment: Agreed, if this was xml (which would have "<" and ">" rather than "[" and "]"), you could just get these attributes of `url` and `image` very easily using the attributes dictionary retrieved by `NSXMLParser` method `didStartElement`. If you're stuck with this format with the square brackets, then I'd probably be inclined to use a `NSScanner`. You can also use `NSRegularExpression`, but for a very general implementation, the scanner might be better.

Answer (score 0):

if ur response is constant then you can do this way

```
NSString *temp=@"[bpfb_link url='http://www.abcd.com/' title='abcd Technologies : : Home Page' image='http://www.abcd.com//images/itwall_b1.gif'] [/bpfb_link]";
    NSArray *arr=[[NSArray alloc]init];
    arr=[temp componentsSeparatedByString:@"'"];
    NSLog(@"arr %@",[arr objectAtIndex:1]);
```

out put is-- http://www.abcd.com/